# What is the equivalent approach of LayoutBuilder of Flutter in the Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

An adaptive layout that is driven by the screen size. This is the basic idea and I use `LayoutBuilder`in the Flutter project, and how about in the Compose?

Comment: Checkout [`BoxWithConstraints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#boxwithconstraints).

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#layout-modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout BoxWithConstraints.

It works very well.